# how to align div right with flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

i already build a hero image where the div element is on the left side, but now i would like to change it and put it on the right side.

I'm new with flexbox and i hope ya could help me out with that

```
<section class="error-image">
  <div class="container hero-container" >
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-12">
        <h1>Pulse Model Management</h1>
        <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer a dipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa.
        Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula,
        </p>
        <a href="Request/index.html" class="btn cta-button float-md-left float-sm-none">Try for free</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

The CSS:

The `hero-container` has the flexbox style

```
.hero-container {
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

and the `.error-image` container the background image

```
.error-image{
background: url(../img/404.jpg);
height: 100vh;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
background-position: center;}
```

Here is an image of it, how it looks right now, i added with photoshop a border, to display where it should be, i tried everything with `flex-end` etc. but it didnt worked for me.

[image: preview]

Comment: How is the image applied? On which element and or as background image?

Comment: its a background image the container `.error-image` has it. Here are the styles. I also updated the question, wich includes now the bg-image container.

`.error-image{background: url(../img/404.jpg);
height: 100vh;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
background-position: center;}`

Comment: Have you tried using `align-items: flex-end` at your `hero-container` and giving `width` and `margin` to your `div class="col-md-8 col-sm-12"` ?

Comment: Is the site live? Would be much easier for me to debug this if so. Or maybe you can set up a CodePen?

Comment: i uploaded it for you.

http://test.awesom-media.de/404.html

Comment: why don't you add a snippet here ?

Comment: Try `.hero-container > row { display: flex; justify-content: flex-end; }`

Comment: that worked for me. thank you dude. made my day